# Login to internet provider directly from router

Tags: router

I have to login to Cyberoam Client with my username and password to use the internet services. I have plugged in the WAN cable into my router, with which I am able to use that internet on many systems.

I have to login on each system separately - that is fine.

But the problem is - When I shut down one system or it is inactive for some time, the other systems' internet stops because the system that shut down has logged off from the Cyberoam Client.

Is there any way I can login to the Provider from within my router only and no need to login separately from each of the system?

Answer (score 1):

If I read the product information on the website, I can see:

"*Cyberoam Transparent Authentication Suite (CTAS) is the Clientless Single Sign On (SSO) for Cyberoam Identity-based UTM appliances. It authenticates users **to access multiple applications through a single username and password**. It also eliminates the installation of SSO clients on each workstation and delivers a high level of protection.*"

Which means, that you didn't do anything wrong, which means (I think) that they made a mistake.

I suggest you **logout** on every system and after that, **login** only on one system **every time**. (You login into a system, when you've finished your session you **logout**)